# Django - Legacy MySQL data migration errors

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm having many issues with foreign key definitions that I have `inspectdb`'d into my models.py file.

I had a set of legacy tables that I wanted to incorporated into my Django app and so I ran `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`

There are 7 GPS tables that I wanted to use in my app. Looking at 2 of them will sufficiently describe the issues I'm having.

MySQL create table statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `gps` (
  `longitude_dir` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(8,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(7,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `host_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `latitude_dir` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `host` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `altitude_units` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gps_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `raw` blob NOT NULL,
  `clean` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_valid` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modem` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `altitude` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`host`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `gps_zda` (
  `local_zone_minutes` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `host` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `year` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `local_zone` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gps_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` time DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `gps_fk_zda` (`gps_id`,`host`),
  CONSTRAINT `gps_fk_zda` FOREIGN KEY (`gps_id`, `host`) REFERENCES `gps` (`id`, `host`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here is a subset of the models

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Gps(models.Model):
    longitude_dir = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=5, blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=5, blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.AutoField()
    host_time = models.DateTimeField()
    latitude_dir = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    host = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    altitude_units = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    gps_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    raw = models.TextField()
    clean = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    data_valid = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    modem = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    altitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'gps'
        unique_together = (('id', 'host'),)

class GpsZda(models.Model):
    local_zone_minutes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    host = models.ForeignKey(Gps, db_column='host')
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    day = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    month = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    local_zone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    gps = models.ForeignKey(Gps)
    timestamp = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'gps_zda'
```

---

1.
So the first problem I ran into when trying to `python manage.py makemigrations` was that `(gps.id, gps.host)` was not properly defined as the primary key. In fact it seemed as though a lot of the contraints were ignored. I received an error at first saying that gps.id was being defined twice.

Changing

```
id = models.Autofield()
...
host = models.CharField(max_length=24)
```

to

```
id = models.Autofield(primary_key=True)
...
host = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=24)
```

let django know not to create it's own id field. I'm still not sure if it's handling the shared key properly.

---

2.
A second issue came up trying to run makemigrations because the gps_zda table has a shared, unique, foreign key. Django complained that it didn't know what to name the second foreign key.

Adding a `related_name` to one of the foreign keys seemed to stop the complaints.

I changed

```
host = models.ForeignKey(Gps, db_column='host')
```

to

```
host = models.ForeignKey(Gps, db_column='host', related_name='gps_zda_host_fk')
```

Once again I'm not sure if this is properly handling the shared foreign key.

---

3.
In order to do some testing, I decided to add the models to admin.py and see if the fields were being populated properly.

This lead to the discovery of more issues.

Issue 3. When I opened a `gps object` I saw that the bit fields (gps.clean, gps.data_valid) were translated to TextFields. I attempted a quick fix on these by simply changing `TextField` to `NullBooleanField`. Now on the admin page I see an appropriate drop down with options: unknown, yes, no. Unfortunately the existing bit value's of 1 are being resolved as unknown.

I'm not sure how to solve this one, it would be problematic to try and change the database structure.

---

4.
Once again in the admin, I can't properly load a gps_zda object. At first I got an error complaining about a non-existent gps_zda.id column. I was able to get around this by changing

```
host = models.ForeignKey(Gps, db_column='host', related_name='gps_zda_host_fk')
...
gps = models.ForeignKey(Gps)
```

to

```
host = models.ForeignKey(Gps, primary_key=True, db_column='host', related_name='gps_zda_host_fk')
...
gps = models.ForeignKey(Gps, primary_key=True)
```

which let Django know not to look for the gps_zda.id field.

I also added `unique_together = (('gps', 'host'),) to the class Meta for GpsZda.

I'm still unable to view the gps_zda data through the admin page however. I receive the following error `gps zda object with primary key u'Arthur' does not exist.` Where `Arthur` is a valid gps.host value.

---

When I started looking at Django I thought it was going to be fun. Not so much. I really question how viable it is to move any existing database into a Django project.

Here are my current models. Any suggestions on how I can make them better work with my tables would be welcomed.

```
class Gps(models.Model):
    longitude_dir = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=5, blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=5, blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    host_time = models.DateTimeField(primary_key=True)
    latitude_dir = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    host = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=24)
    altitude_units = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    gps_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    raw = models.TextField()
    clean = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    data_valid = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    modem = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    altitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'gps'
        unique_together = (('id', 'host'),)

class GpsZda(models.Model):
    local_zone_minutes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    host = models.ForeignKey(Gps, db_column='host', related_name='gps_zda_host_fk')
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    day = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    month = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    local_zone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    gps = models.ForeignKey(Gps, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    timestamp = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'gps_zda'
        unique_together = (('gps', 'host'),)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not currently support composite primary keys in a table. (See [wiki page](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys) and lack of [model meta options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/) which is the place this would be defined.)

The best option is probably to add another identification column to your `gps` table, so Django can work with it properly.

Regarding other issues, it might be best if you research and post separate questions for them.